# Android Firestore get document ID after uploading

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to figure out how to get the document ID after posting to firestore. I can't seem to find an answer online leading me to believe you are unable to.

I find it interesting though because in the onComplete it has a DocumentReference but this does not contain the document reference upon debugging

```
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `task.getResult().getId()` after your creation, this should return the id of the newly created document